# For $f(z) = \sum z^n / n$ what is $f(i / 2)$

Tags: complex-analysis

This is probably a standard complex analysis question. Probably the equality,
$\sum z^n = 1/(1-z)$ is needed. Can you please help?

Answer (score 3):

If your sum is over $n\ge 1$, you can show the function is $-\ln(1-z)$, so you want $-\ln(1-\frac{i}{2})=-\ln(\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\exp -i\arctan\frac12)=i\arctan\frac12-\ln\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that by Taylor series:

$$\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1} z^n}{n}$$
$$\ln(1-x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1} (-z)^n}{n}$$
$$\ln(1-x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} -\frac{z^n}{n}$$
$$-\ln(1-x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n}$$

So $$f(x)=-\ln(1-x)\Rightarrow f(\frac i2)=-\ln(1-\frac i2)=\ln(\frac{2}{2-i})=\ln(\frac 45 + \frac 25 i)=\ln(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}})+\ln(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}i)=\ln(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}})+i\arctan(\frac 12)$$

:)

Comment: You're mixing $x$ and $z$.

Answer (score 0):

Integrate both sides of the equality in your question (and set them equal at $z=0$) to get

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n}=-\ln (1-z) = \ln \frac{1}{1-z}.$$